# Converting Strings to Uppercase with charAt

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a program that asks the user to enter their last name in lower case and asks them if they want it outputted as all caps or with just the first letter capitalised. The problem I'm having is using charAt with toUpperCase.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//This imports the scanner class
public class ChangeCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        //This allows me to use the term scan to indicate when to scan
        String lastName;
        //sets the variable lastName to a string
        int Option;

    System.out.println("Please enter your last name");
    //Prints out a line
    lastName = scan.nextLine();
    //scans the next line of input and assigns it to the lastName variable
    System.out.println("Please select an option:"+'\n'+"1. Make all leters Capitalised"+'\n'+ "2. Make the First letter Capitalised");
    Option = scan.nextInt();
    if (Option == 1){
        System.out.println(lastName.toUpperCase());
    }
    if (Option == 2){
        System.out.println(lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase());

    }
    }

}
```

I get an error saying "Cannot invoke toUpperCase() on the primitive type char"

Comment: Please **edit** your question, and paste the text of your code in (not a link to an image of your code). Once pasted, select the text and press ctrl-k for it to indent the necessary 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply `String.toUpperChase` on a `char` like your error is saying. In the case where you want to make the first letter uppercase you can do something like:

```
    String lastName = "hill";
    String newLastName = lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1);
    System.out.println(newLastName);
```

A sample run of this:

> run:
>   Hill
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

In the case where you want all the letters uppercase, it's as simple as

```
    newLastName = lastName.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(newLastName);
```

A sample run of this:

> run: 
>   HILL 
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Thank you, this helped tremendously.

Comment: @AlexRBurgess Glad to hear it! Don't forget to accept. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I used to try this in C programming in college. Should work here as well.

```
(char)(lastName.charAt(i) - 32)
```

Try the above in System.out.println

The code when we deduct 32 from character it reduces ascii value by 32 and hence gets upper case letter. Just refer an ascii table to understand what I am trying to tell by deduction of 32 places in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As your error is telling you, you can't invoke [`String.toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) on a primitive `char` type.

```
System.out.println(lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
```

**But**, you can invoke [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-) like

```
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(lastName.charAt(0)));
```

**Or**, call `String.toUpperCase()` and then take the first character. Like,

```
System.out.println(lastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
```